# I m geting only one item back to recyclerview my from Room datatabase

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, fragment

As I have implemented a room library in my project ,
I add data to database , But Recyclerview is showing only one item .

```
class NotesAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<NotesAdapter.NotesViewHolder>() {

class NotesViewHolder(val binding: NotesCardLayoutBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

private val differCallback = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Notes>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Notes, newItem: Notes): Boolean {
        return oldItem.noteId == newItem.noteId
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Notes, newItem: Notes): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }

}
val differ = AsyncListDiffer(this,differCallback)

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NotesViewHolder {
    val view =
        NotesCardLayoutBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
    return NotesViewHolder(view)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NotesViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val notes = differ.currentList[position]

    holder.binding.tvTitle.text = notes.noteTitle.toString()
    holder.binding.tvDesc.text = notes.notesDesc.toString()
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return differ.currentList.size
}
```

}

" My Notes Fragment where recylerview is intialized "

```
class NotesFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentNotesBinding
 private lateinit var notesViewModel: NotesViewModel
    private lateinit var notesAdapter : NotesAdapter

    

    private fun recyclerviewSetup() {
         notesAdapter = NotesAdapter()
        val recyclerView = binding.rvNotes
        recyclerView.adapter = notesAdapter
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
        activity?.let {
            notesViewModel.getAllNotes.observe(viewLifecycleOwner , Observer { noteList->
                notesAdapter.differ.submitList(noteList)
            })
        }
    }

}
```

It may be the problem of database or Adapter
please gyzz help me out
[github](https://github.com/ashgautamDev/NoteApp)

Comment: I remove code from note fragement  to post here because it saying lot of code

Comment: I would suggest you to first check whether the data is stored properly in database or not. i.e. first check whether your database has more than one rows
You can print the size of your data and the items stored in database in logcat.
This way we can be sure that, the database is correctly functioning and then we can move to Adapter for further debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with fetching data, I've cloned your repo and checked, it is while inserting, do not user `Int?` for primary key, just use `Int`

***Notes.kt***

```
@Entity(tableName = "Notes Table")
data class Notes(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var noteId: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "Title of Notes")
    val noteTitle: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "Description of Notes")
    val notesDesc: String?
)
```

Also you have another problem is `notes_card_layout`, you are setting height to `match_parent` which is not correct, use below

***notes_card_layout.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >

        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginVertical="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                android:text="@string/title_card" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvDesc"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                android:text="@string/desc_card" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

replace above two code snippets and try, below is a snapshot from my modified changes

[image]